# Removing SQL Server 2008 R2 completely

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, uninstallation

I installed SQL Server 2008 R2 on my Windows 7 64bit machine.

Then I lost the ownership and user id of the database I created.

So I decided to uninstall the whole thing. I stopped all the services, and under control panel `add/remove program`,  I removed everything.

I then restarted the PC and install the SQL Server 2008 R2 but I still see the old database.

What am I doing wrong ?

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: The database is your "document," it is not deleted when you uninstall the server (same as your documents are not deleted when you uninstall Word). Detach the DB from the server and delete the data files from the Data folder.

Comment: If you successfully uninstalled/reinstalled, you will likely "see" the old database files on disk.  But you shouldn't "see" the database in Sql Server Management Studio.  That being said, I agree with what @GSerg suggested.